# enable ssl connection filezilla throught powershell

Tags: powershell, ftp, filezilla, ftps

is there any way to enable ssl/tls on a running filezilla ftp server using powershell script? 
i found info on how to do it in iis ([here](https://serverfault.com/questions/281316/powershell-set-iis-7-5-ftp-site-to-allow-ssl-connections)) but not for filezilla.
any tip?

Answer (score 0):

If it were  me, I'd change the config file called `FileZilla Server.xml` to have the settings you need.  You may have to make the change on a test server first to know exactly what to change.  I'd then make a script to open up the config file on all of those servers as XML and use XML specific methods (like .SetAttribute()) to change the config.  You can find out more about how to parse XML here: http://tfl09.blogspot.com/2010/07/powershell-and-xml-element-attributes.html or on several other great articles throughout the web.

This config file is probably only read when the service is restarted, so you can use Get-Service to restart the service remotely.

If you have a more specific question during those processes, make sure to come back and search stack overflow and post more questions if you can't find the answers.